# Program stops at for loop

Tags: c, string, char

I'm experimenting with C and trying to get used to memory and string stuff by creating a program that takes stdin in the form of words, processes the words, spits them back out and also tries changing the word's upper and lower cases.

However, it seems like the program doesn't execute anything beyond `strcpy(key, word)`. It stops right at the for loop, and doesn't even execute the print statements after the loop.

So far, I've tried both a while loop and a for loop for the case changing. I made sure key copied correctly by printf'ing it on the line above the for loop. I even commented out the for loop and saw the tolower() call two lines worked and printed out the updated key. There's just something wrong with the for loop and I don't know what.

How would I be able to fix it?

```
int main(void)
{
    char ch; 
    char *word;
    word = (char *)malloc(60 * sizeof(char)); 
    int ind = 0; 
    int cap = 60; 
    while (ch = getchar()) { 
        if (isalnum(ch)) {
            if (ind >= cap) {
                word = (char *)realloc(word, (ind + 1) * sizeof(char));
                cap++; 
            }
            word[ind] = ch; 
            ind++; 
        } else {
            word[ind] = '\0'; 
            int size = strlen(word); 
            char key[size]; 
            strcpy(key, word); 
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                if (i = 0) {
                    key[i] = toupper(key[i]);
                } else {
                    key[i] = tolower(key[i]);
                }
            }
            fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", key);
            key[0] = tolower(key[0]);
            fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", key);
            ind = 0; 
            memset(word, 0, sizeof word);
            putchar(ch); 
            putchar('\n');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `char key[size];` -> `char key[size + 1];`, you need one char more for the string NUL terminator. There may be more problems though.

Comment: `if (i = 0)` -> `if (i == 0)`. Also `memset(word, 0, sizeof word)` is fishy. Why not just `word[0] = 0` or `*word = 0`? I suggest you learn how to use your debugger. The time invested will quickly pay off.

Comment: oh oops, forgot about the ==. I used memset purely because I searched up how to empty a char array and one of the threads on this forum recommended that way. The idea is for the user to be able to continue writing words and lines. I will try what you are suggesting too

Comment: Have you tried running your program in a debugger and examine what it does?

Comment: BTW: `memset(word, 0, sizeof word)` or the replacement I suggested is not neccesary at because you're overwriting the `word` buffer it anyway on the next loop run.

Comment: update! I got it to work after I fixed i==0! I wonder why the compiler didn't yell at me for a syntax error before running it? oh well, thanks @Jabberwocky!

Comment: @Manaal because it's not a syntax error, it's valid C, but often compiler's emit a warning for this, because people often get it wrong.

Comment: @Manaal BTW: `memset(word, 0, sizeof word)` doesn't emtpy the whole buffer, `sizeof word` is not the size of the memory `word` points to, but it's the size of a pointer (usually 4 or 8 depending on your platform), and if the size of the buffer is less then 4 (or 8), you'll be writing beyond the end of the buffer. You wanted actually `memset(word, 0, strlen(word))`.

Comment: Always compile with *warnings enabled*, and **do not** accept code until it *compiles without warning*. To enable warnings add `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` to your `gcc/clang` compile string (also consider adding `-Wshadow` to warn on shadowed variables). For **VS** (`cl.exe` on windows), use `/W3`. All other compilers will have similar options. Read and understand each warning -- then go fix it. They will identify any problems, and the exact line on which they occur. You can learn a lot by listening to what your compiler is telling you.

Comment: e.g. `"warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]  if (i = 0) {"` and `"warning: argument to ‘sizeof’ in ‘memset’ call is the same expression as the destination; did you mean to provide an explicit length? [-Wsizeof-pointer-memaccess]  memset(word, 0, sizeof word);"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- `ch` must be defined with type `int` for proper detection of `EOF`. The return value of `fgetc()` can be a byte value (all values of type `unsigned char`) or the special negative value `EOF`. Converting to type `char` looses information.
- `while (ch = getchar())` cannot detect end of file, it only tests if the byte read from the file is non zero. You should write `while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF)`.
- you do not allocate space for the null terminator. More precisely, you should allow for 2 extra bytes when testing for the reallocation of the target buffer.
- when reallocating the array, you should increase `cap` by more than 1 to avoid reallocating for each extra byte you need to store.
- `int size = strlen(word);` can be replaced with `int size = ind;`.
- `char key[size];` is incorrect: you should allow for the null terminator by allocating one extra byte.
- `isalnum()`, `toupper()`, `tolower()` and the other functions from `<ctype.h>` are only defined for all values returned by `getchar()`. Negative argument values different than `EOF` cause undefined behavior, a `char` argument must be cast as `(unsigned char)` to avoid undefined behavior on architectures where `char` is signed by default.
- `memset(word, 0, sizeof word);` is useless.
- you do not test for allocation failure.
- you never free `word`.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int ch; 
    int ind = 0; 
    int cap = 60;
    char *word = malloc(60); 

    if (word == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "allocation failure\n");
        return 1;
    }
    while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) { 
        if (isalnum(ch)) {
            if (ind >= cap) {
                cap += cap / 2;
                word = realloc(word, cap);
                if (word == NULL) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "allocation failure\n");
                    return 1;
                }
            }
            word[ind] = ch; 
            ind++; 
        } else {
            word[ind] = '\0'; 
            char key[ind]; 
            strcpy(key, word);
            if (ind > 0) {
                key[0] = toupper((unsigned char)key[0]);
                for (int i = 1; i < ind; i++) {
                    key[i] = tolower((unsigned char)key[i]);
                }
            }
            printf("%s\n", key);
            key[0] = tolower((unsigned char)key[0]);
            printf("%s\n", key);
            ind = 0;
            putchar(ch); 
            putchar('\n');
        }
    }
    free(word);
    return 0;
}
```